# What is the most efficient way to load a user's DirectoryEntry?

Tags: c#, .net, optimization, active-directory

I have the following code that loads a user's Active Directory DirectoryEntry object from the user's SID:

```
public static DirectoryEntry GetUserDirectoryEntry(SecurityIdentifier sid)
{
    return new DirectoryEntry(string.Format("LDAP://<SID={0}>", sid.Value));
}
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this? I'm having to optimize my code because of performance issues, and I need to squeeze down to the absolute fastest code that I can. It doesn't necessarily have to load from an SID. I just need to know the most efficient way to get the users DirectoryEntry.

EDIT: I'm restricted to using .Net 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it makes a big difference how you load your DirectoryEntry - whether by SID or by fully-qualified DN - it just takes a set amount of time for the AD bind operation to work

That bind actually doesn't happen when you instantiate your DirectoryEntry - it's delayed until you start using properties on your DirectoryEntry, or access the `.NativeObject` property.

So no matter which way you do it - creating your DirectoryEntry based on some uniquely identifying value will just take its time.

Marc

Answer (score 2):

Directory operations are fairly slow regardless of the means you use to access objects in the directory.  Without more context it is difficult to recommend a more efficient approach, but in general, have you considered grabbing sets of users at once, multithreading, and caching to design around the issue?

Also, I cannot say which is more efficient, but have you tried the new [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx) namespace in .NET 3.5?  If anyone **should** have optimized this, it would be Microsoft, but I think we have all been let down before.

Comment: I edited the question to add that I'm restricted to using .Net 2.0. Also, I only need to pull one user at a time.

Answer (score 1):

You should try defining more filters and specifying user as the type in your criteria.

Comment: I'm not doing a search. Are you saying it would be more efficient to use a directory searcher class?

Comment: By search I meant you are using LDAP query (searching the AD). Every LDAP query you run, count as a search.

Answer (score 1):

What about the [System.DirectoryServices.Protocols](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.protocols(VS.80).aspx) namespace.  It doesn't have the overhead of using ADSI and ought to be a lot faster.  It looks a bit unwieldy at the start but once you get used to it, it's no so bad.  Plus you can do proper asynchronous searches.

Have a look at:

- [Introduction to System.DirectoryServices.Protocols (S.DS.P)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb332056.aspx)
- [S.DS and large data sets](http://blogs.dirteam.com/blogs/tomek/archive/2007/05/18/s-ds-and-large-data-sets.aspx)
- [PAGING IN SYSTEM.DIRECTORYSERVICES.PROTOCOLS](http://dunnry.com/blog/PagingInSystemDirectoryServicesProtocols.aspx)
- [PAGED ASYNCHRONOUS LDAP SEARCHES REVISITED](http://dunnry.com/blog/CategoryView,category,Protocols.aspx)